# Understating binomial and uniform distributions.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Speaking of probability distribution, Can someone kindly tell **how** and **when** I use binomial distribution and uniform distribution in real life situations? I understand their mathematical formulas but I want to be able to choose the right one to perform when a certain problem is given to me to analyze.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As general guidelines:

(1) Use the (discrete) uniform distribution when you are choosing one of $n$ items with the choice of any given item being equally likely.  (Rolling a fair $n$-sided die.)

(2) Use the binomial distribution when you are performing $n$ trials each of which results in one of two outcomes ('success' or 'failure') where the probability of success on any trial is the same as on any other trial.  You are interested in the total number of successes in the $n$ trials).  (Seeing how many  defective lightbulbs there are in a batch of $10$ lightbulbs.)

Comment: Thank you for this explanation .

Answer (score 0):

Gambling is a classic source of examples.
You and a friend have a fair, 9-sided die. He says he'll give you $k$ dollars roll the die and call it right. Call $X$ the number that shows, then $X\sim\text{unif}[1,2,\dotsc,9]$. Since $E[X] = \frac{10}{2} = 5$, your best guess is to call a $5$. The probability that you win by calling $j$ correctly is
$$P(X = j) = \frac{1}{9}.$$

Now he says to play a different game. He says he will pay you $k$ dollars if you call the number of sixes in 10 rolls. We, you have $n = 10$ independent rolls (trials) with probability $p = \frac{1}{9}$ of rolling a six (success). Call $Y$ the number of sixes in 10 rolls, then $Y\sim \text{Bin}(10, \frac{1}{9})$. Since $E[Y] = 10\cdot \frac{1}{9}$, your best guess is to say you will only roll one six. The probability that you are correct is
$$P(Y = 1) = \binom{10}{1}\left(\frac{1}{9}\right)^1\left(\frac{8}{9}\right)^9 =0.3849327.$$
You can do further analysis on whether $k$ is a fair price or not.

Comment: Thank you for your post :)